# Microsoft bing maps pushpin (web javascript)

Tags: bing-maps

Is it possible to create pushpins from addresses instead of lat/long data?

I guess the pushpin constructor accepts only locations which are a lat/long representation of the location.

new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(value)

Is there any solution for creating pushpins from addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code showing you how to find a location by address:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>searchbyaddressHTML</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <style type='text/css'>body{margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;font-family:'Segoe UI',Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='printoutPanel'></div>

        <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function loadMapScenario() {
                var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    /* No need to set credentials if already passed in URL */
                    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.624527, -122.355255),
                    zoom: 8 });
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                    var searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                    var requestOptions = {
                        bounds: map.getBounds(),
                        where: 'Washington, DC',
                        callback: function (answer, userData) {
                            map.setView({ bounds: answer.results[0].bestView });
                            map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(answer.results[0].location));
                        }
                    };
                    searchManager.geocode(requestOptions);
                });

            }
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=YourBingMapsKey&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u @daveTheCoder, ok I have already seen this in the documentation. But imagine the case of large data, making this call for every pushpin will not be performant I guess. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @dev not sure what your exact use case is. But maybe using Bing Maps spatial data services may be of help for you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh698204.aspx You can use the Query API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx